# how to load page automatically?

Tags: php, jquery, html, paypal

how to load another page without click ? i have created site its there paypal options there.here my code i want load without click likn option load to paypal code ? here my code?

```
<p><form name="form1" method="post" action="shopping_cart/paypal.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="courseid" id="courseid" value="55" />
 <input type="hidden" name="coursename" id="coursename" value="Video Modeling Course" />
 <a href= "#" onclick="document['form1'].submit()">Buy: $50.00 <img src="images/paypal_logo2.gif" alt="PayPal" width="210" height="80" border="0" />
 </a>
 </form>
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want to submit the form as soon as the page loads, instead of on click of the `a` element? If so just call `document['form1'].submit()` immediately.

Comment: Please make your problem statement a bit more clear,not understanding it.

Comment: varun in my page load paypal if i click paypal button but i want load automatically paypal

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan My code   onclick page there is its load paypal function code .but i want load without click  load to paypal code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the code below (after html loads), which submit form, see example below:

```
<p><form name="form1" method="post" action="shopping_cart/paypal.php">
 <input type="hidden" name="courseid" id="courseid" value="55" />
 <input type="hidden" name="coursename" id="coursename" value="Video Modeling Course" />
 <a href= "#" onclick="document['form1'].submit()">Buy: $50.00 <img src="images/paypal_logo2.gif" alt="PayPal" width="210" height="80" border="0" />
 </a>
 </form>
<script>document['form1'].submit()</script>
```

In jQuery it would be:

```
<script>$('form[name="form1"]').submit();</script>
```